# How to compile a .java file, which tools and datas need?

Tags: java, import, compilation, structure

I have this .java datafile. The data file is a part of an imagej plugin.
The whole data structure is here:
[enter link description here](https://github.com/krzysg/MosaicSuite/tree/master/src/main/java/mosaic)

```
package mosaic.plugins;

import ij.IJ;
import ij.ImagePlus;
import ij.macro.Interpreter;
import ij.measure.ResultsTable;
import ij.process.ByteProcessor;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.TreeMap;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

import mosaic.plugins.utils.PlugIn8bitBase;
import net.imglib2.Cursor;
import net.imglib2.IterableInterval;
import net.imglib2.RandomAccess;
import net.imglib2.img.ImagePlusAdapter;
import net.imglib2.img.Img;
import net.imglib2.img.ImgFactory;
import net.imglib2.img.array.ArrayImgFactory;
import net.imglib2.img.display.imagej.ImageJFunctions;
import net.imglib2.type.NativeType;
import net.imglib2.type.numeric.NumericType;
import net.imglib2.type.numeric.RealType;
import net.imglib2.type.numeric.integer.UnsignedByteType;
import net.imglib2.type.numeric.real.FloatType;
import net.imglib2.view.IntervalView;
import net.imglib2.view.Views;


public class Naturalization extends PlugIn8bitBase
{
    // Precision in finding your best T
    private static final float EPS = 0.0001f;

    // Prior parameter for first oder
    // In this case is for all channels
    // Fixed parameter
    private static final float T1_pr = 0.3754f;

    // Number of bins for the Laplacian Histogram
    // In general is 4 * N_Grad
    // max of laplacian value is 4 * 255
    private static final int N_Lap = 2041;

    // Offset shift in the histogram bins
    // Has to be N_Lap / 2;
    private static final int Lap_Offset = 1020;

    // Number of bins for the Gradient
    private static final int N_Grad = 512;

    // Offset for the gradient histogram shift
    private static final int Grad_Offset = 256;

    // Prior parameter for second order (Parameters learned from trained data set)
    // For different color R G B
    // For one channel image use an average of them
    private final float T2_pr[] = {0.2421f ,0.2550f, 0.2474f, 0.24816666f};

    // Keeps values of PSNR for all images and channels in case of RGB. Maps: imageNumber -> map (channel, PSNR value)
    private final Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Float>> iPsnrOutput = new TreeMap<Integer, Map<Integer, Float>>();
    private synchronized void addPsnr(int aSlice, int aChannel, float aValue) {
        Map<Integer, Float> map = iPsnrOutput.get(aSlice);
        boolean isNewMap = false;
        if (map == null) {
            map = new TreeMap<Integer, Float>();
            isNewMap = true;
        }
        map.put(aChannel, aValue);
        if (isNewMap) {
            iPsnrOutput.put(aSlice, map);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void processImg(ByteProcessor aOutputImg, ByteProcessor aOrigImg, int aChannelNumber) {
        // perform naturalization
        final ImagePlus naturalizedImg = naturalize8bitImage(aOrigImg, aChannelNumber);

        // set processed pixels to output image
        aOutputImg.setPixels(naturalizedImg.getProcessor().getPixels());
    }

    @Override
    protected void postprocessBeforeShow() {
        // Create result table with all stored PSNRs.
        final ResultsTable rs = new ResultsTable();
        for (final Entry<Integer, Map<Integer, Float>> e : iPsnrOutput.entrySet()) {
            rs.incrementCounter();
            for (final Entry<Integer, Float> m : e.getValue().entrySet()) {
                switch(m.getKey()) {
                    case CHANNEL_R: rs.addValue("Naturalization R", m.getValue()); rs.addValue("Estimated R PSNR", calculate_PSNR(m.getValue())); break;
                    case CHANNEL_G: rs.addValue("Naturalization G", m.getValue()); rs.addValue("Estimated G PSNR", calculate_PSNR(m.getValue())); break;
                    case CHANNEL_B: rs.addValue("Naturalization B", m.getValue()); rs.addValue("Estimated B PSNR", calculate_PSNR(m.getValue())); break;
                    case CHANNEL_8G: rs.addValue("Naturalization", m.getValue()); rs.addValue("Estimated PSNR", calculate_PSNR(m.getValue())); break;
                    default: break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!Interpreter.isBatchMode()) {
            rs.show("Naturalization and PSNR");
            showMessage();
        }
    }

    private ImagePlus naturalize8bitImage(ByteProcessor imp, int aChannelNumber) {
        Img<UnsignedByteType> TChannel = ImagePlusAdapter.wrap(new ImagePlus("", imp));
        final float T2_prior = T2_pr[(aChannelNumber <= CHANNEL_B) ? 2-aChannelNumber : CHANNEL_8G];
        final float[] result = {0.0f}; // ugly but one of ways to get result back via parameters;

        // Perform naturalization and store PSNR result. Finally return image in ImageJ format.
        TChannel = performNaturalization(TChannel, T2_prior, result);
        addPsnr(imp.getSliceNumber(), aChannelNumber, result[0]);

        return ImageJFunctions.wrap(TChannel,"temporaryName");
    }

    /**
     * Naturalize the image
     * @param Img original image
     * @param Theta parameter
     * @param Class<T> Original image
     * @param Class<S> Calculation Type
     * @param T2_prior Prior to use
     * @param result One element array to store nautralization factor
     */
    private <T extends NumericType<T> & NativeType<T> & RealType<T>, S extends RealType<S>> Img<T> doNaturalization(Img<T> image_orig, S Theta,Class<T> cls_t, float T2_prior, float[] result) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException
    {
        if (image_orig == null) {return null;}

        // Check that the image data set is 8 bit
        // Otherwise return an error or hint to scale down
        final T image_check = cls_t.newInstance();
        final Object obj = image_check;
        if (!(obj instanceof UnsignedByteType)) {
            IJ.error("Error it work only with 8-bit type");
            return null;
        }

        final float Nf = findNaturalizationFactor(image_orig, Theta, T2_prior);
        result[0] = Nf;
        final Img<T> image_result = naturalizeImage(image_orig, Nf, cls_t);

        return image_result;
    }

    private <S extends RealType<S>, T extends NumericType<T> & NativeType<T> & RealType<T>>
    Img<T> naturalizeImage(Img<T> image_orig, float Nf, Class<T> cls_t)
            throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException
            {
        // Mean of the original image
        //        S mean_original = cls_s.newInstance();
        //        Mean<T,S> m = new Mean<T,S>();
        //        m.compute(image_orig.cursor(), mean_original);
        // TODO: quick fix for deprecated code above. Is new 'mean' utility introduced in imglib2?
        float mean_original = 0.0f;

        final Cursor<T> c2 = image_orig.cursor();
        float count = 0.0f;
        while (c2.hasNext()) {
            c2.next();
            mean_original += c2.get().getRealFloat();
            count += 1.0f;
        }
        mean_original /= count;

        // Create result image
        final long[] origImgDimensions = new long[2];
        image_orig.dimensions(origImgDimensions);
        final Img<T> image_result = image_orig.factory().create(origImgDimensions, cls_t.newInstance());

        // for each pixel naturalize
        final Cursor<T> cur_orig = image_orig.cursor();
        final Cursor<T> cur_ir = image_result.cursor();

        while (cur_orig.hasNext()) {
            cur_orig.next();
            cur_ir.next();

            final float tmp = cur_orig.get().getRealFloat();

            // Naturalize
            float Nat = (int) ((tmp - mean_original)*Nf + mean_original + 0.5);
            if (Nat < 0)
            {Nat = 0;}
            else if (Nat > 255)
            {Nat = 255;}

            cur_ir.get().setReal(Nat);
        }
        return image_result;
            }

    private <S extends RealType<S>, T extends NumericType<T> & NativeType<T> & RealType<T>> float findNaturalizationFactor(Img<T> image_orig, S Theta, float T2prior) {
        final ImgFactory<FloatType> imgFactoryF = new ArrayImgFactory<FloatType>();

        // Create one dimensional image (Histogram)
        final Img<FloatType> LapCDF = imgFactoryF.create(new long[] {N_Lap}, new FloatType());

        // Two dimensional image for Gradient
        final Img<FloatType> GradCDF = imgFactoryF.create(new long[] {N_Grad, 2}, new FloatType());

        // GradientCDF = Integral of the histogram of the of the Gradient field
        // LaplacianCDF = Integral of the Histogram of the Laplacian field
        final Img<FloatType> GradD = create2DGradientField();
        calculateLaplaceFieldAndGradient(image_orig, LapCDF, GradD);
        convertGrad2dToCDF(GradD);
        calculateGradCDF(GradCDF, GradD);
        calculateLapCDF(LapCDF);

        // For each channel find the best T1
        // EPS=precision
        // for X component
        float T_tmp = (float)FindT(Views.iterable(Views.hyperSlice(GradCDF, GradCDF.numDimensions()-1 , 0)), N_Grad, Grad_Offset, EPS);
        // for Y component
        T_tmp += FindT(Views.iterable(Views.hyperSlice(GradCDF, GradCDF.numDimensions()-1 , 1)), N_Grad, Grad_Offset, EPS);
        // Average them and divide by the prior parameter
        final float T1 = T_tmp/(2*T1_pr);

        // Find the best parameter and divide by the T2 prior
        final float T2 = (float)FindT(LapCDF, N_Lap, Lap_Offset, EPS)/T2prior;

        // Calculate naturalization factor!
        final float Nf = (float) ((1.0-Theta.getRealDouble())*T1 + Theta.getRealDouble()*T2);

        return Nf;
    }

    /**
     * Calculate the peak SNR from the Naturalization factor
     *
     * @param Nf naturalization factor
     * @return the PSNR
     */
    String calculate_PSNR(double x)
    {
        if (x >=  0 && x <= 0.934)
        {
            return String.format("%.2f", new Float(23.65 * Math.exp(0.6 * x) - 20.0 * Math.exp(-7.508 * x)));
        }
        else if (x > 0.934 && x < 1.07)
        {
            return new String("> 40");
        }
        else if (x >= 1.07 && x < 1.9)
        {
            return String.format("%.2f", new Float(-11.566 * x + 52.776));
        }
        else
        {
            return String.format("%.2f",new Float(13.06*x*x*x*x - 121.4 * x*x*x + 408.5 * x*x -595.5*x + 349));
        }
    }

    private Img<UnsignedByteType> performNaturalization(Img<UnsignedByteType> channel, float T2_prior, float[] result) {
        // Parameters balance between first order and second order
        final FloatType Theta = new FloatType(0.5f);
        try {
            channel = doNaturalization(channel, Theta, UnsignedByteType.class, T2_prior, result);
        } catch (final InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (final IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return channel;
    }

    // Original data
    // N = nuber of bins
    // offset of the histogram
    // T current
    private double FindT_Evalue(float[] p_d, int N, int offset, float T)
    {
        double error = 0;

        for (int i=-offset; i<N-offset; ++i) {
            final double tmp = Math.atan(T*(i)) - p_d[i+offset];
            error += (tmp*tmp);
        }

        return error;
    }

    // Find the T
    // data CDF Histogram
    // N number of bins
    // Offset of the histogram
    // eps precision
    private double FindT(IterableInterval<FloatType> data, int N, int OffSet, float eps)
    {
        //find the best parameter between data and model atan(Tx)/pi+0.5

        // Search between 0 and 1.0
        float left = 0;
        float right = 1.0f;

        float m1 = 0.0f;
        float m2 = 0.0f;

        // Crate p_t to save computation (shift and rescale the original CDF)
        final float p_t[] = new float[N];

        // Copy the data
        final Cursor<FloatType> cur_data = data.cursor();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        {
            cur_data.next();
            p_t[i] = (float) ((cur_data.get().getRealFloat() - 0.5)*Math.PI);
        }

        // While the precision is bigger than eps
        while (right-left>=eps)
        {
            // move left and right of 1/3 (m1 and m2)
            m1=left+(right-left)/3;
            m2=right-(right-left)/3;

            // Evaluate on m1 and m2, ane move the extreme point
            if (FindT_Evalue(p_t, N, OffSet, m1) <=FindT_Evalue(p_t, N, OffSet, m2)) {
                right=m2;
            }
            else {
                left=m1;
            }
        }

        // return the average
        return (m1+m2)/2;
    }

    private Img<FloatType> create2DGradientField() {
        final long dims[] = new long[2];
        dims[0] = N_Grad;
        dims[1] = N_Grad;
        final Img<FloatType> GradD = new ArrayImgFactory<FloatType>().create(dims, new FloatType());
        return GradD;
    }

    private void calculateLapCDF(Img<FloatType> LapCDF) {
        final RandomAccess<FloatType> Lap_hist2 = LapCDF.randomAccess();
        //convert Lap to CDF
        for (int i = 1; i < N_Lap; ++i)
        {
            Lap_hist2.setPosition(i-1,0);
            final float prec = Lap_hist2.get().getRealFloat();
            Lap_hist2.move(1,0);
            Lap_hist2.get().set(Lap_hist2.get().getRealFloat() + prec);
        }
    }

    private void calculateGradCDF(Img<FloatType> GradCDF, Img<FloatType> GradD) {
        final RandomAccess<FloatType> Grad_dist = GradD.randomAccess();

        // Gradient on x pointer
        final IntervalView<FloatType> Gradx = Views.hyperSlice(GradCDF, GradCDF.numDimensions()-1 , 0);
        // Gradient on y pointer
        final IntervalView<FloatType> Grady = Views.hyperSlice(GradCDF, GradCDF.numDimensions()-1 , 1);

        integrateOverRowAndCol(Grad_dist, Gradx, Grady);

        scaleGradiens(Gradx, Grady);
    }

    private void scaleGradiens(IntervalView<FloatType> Gradx, IntervalView<FloatType> Grady) {
        final RandomAccess<FloatType> Gradx_r2 = Gradx.randomAccess();
        final RandomAccess<FloatType> Grady_r2 = Grady.randomAccess();
        //scale, divide the number of integrated bins
        for (int i = 0; i < N_Grad; ++i)
        {
            Gradx_r2.setPosition(i,0);
            Grady_r2.setPosition(i,0);
            Gradx_r2.get().set((float) (Gradx_r2.get().getRealFloat() / 255.0));
            Grady_r2.get().set((float) (Grady_r2.get().getRealFloat() / 255.0));
        }
    }

    private void integrateOverRowAndCol(RandomAccess<FloatType> Grad_dist, IntervalView<FloatType> Gradx, IntervalView<FloatType> Grady) {
        final int[] loc = new int[2];
        // pGrad2D has 2D CDF
        final RandomAccess<FloatType> Gradx_r = Gradx.randomAccess();

        // Integrate over the row
        for (int i = 0; i < N_Grad; ++i)
        {
            loc[1] = i;
            Gradx_r.setPosition(i,0);

            // get the row
            for (int j = 0; j < N_Grad; ++j)
            {
                loc[0] = j;

                // Set the position
                Grad_dist.setPosition(loc);

                // integrate over the row to get 1D vector
                Gradx_r.get().set(Gradx_r.get().getRealFloat() + Grad_dist.get().getRealFloat());
            }
        }

        final RandomAccess<FloatType> Grady_r = Grady.randomAccess();

        // Integrate over the column
        for (int i = 0; i < N_Grad; ++i)
        {
            loc[1] = i;
            Grady_r.setPosition(0,0);

            for (int j = 0; j < N_Grad; ++j)
            {
                loc[0] = j;
                Grad_dist.setPosition(loc);
                Grady_r.get().set(Grady_r.get().getRealFloat() + Grad_dist.get().getRealFloat());
                Grady_r.move(1,0);
            }
        }
    }

    private <T extends RealType<T>> void calculateLaplaceFieldAndGradient(Img<T> image, Img<FloatType> LapCDF, Img<FloatType> GradD) {
        final RandomAccess<FloatType> Grad_dist = GradD.randomAccess();
        final long[] origImgDimensions = new long[2];
        image.dimensions(origImgDimensions);
        final Img<FloatType> laplaceField = new ArrayImgFactory<FloatType>().create(origImgDimensions, new FloatType());

        // Cursor localization
        final int[] indexD = new int[2];
        final int[] loc_p = new int[2];
        final RandomAccess<T> img_cur = image.randomAccess();
        final RandomAccess<FloatType> Lap_f = laplaceField.randomAccess();
        final RandomAccess<FloatType> Lap_hist = LapCDF.randomAccess();


        // Normalization 1/(Number of pixel of the original image)
        long n_pixel = 1;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < laplaceField.numDimensions() ; i++)
        {n_pixel *= laplaceField.dimension(i)-2;}
        // unit to sum
        final double f = 1.0/(n_pixel);

        // Inside the image for Y
        final Cursor<FloatType> cur = laplaceField.cursor();

        // For each point of the Laplacian field
        while (cur.hasNext())
        {
            cur.next();

            // Localize cursors
            cur.localize(loc_p);

            // Exclude the border
            boolean border = false;

            for (int i = 0 ; i < image.numDimensions() ; i++)
            {
                if (loc_p[i] == 0)
                {border = true;}
                else if (loc_p[i] == image.dimension(i)-1)
                {border = true;}
            }

            if (border == true) {
                continue;
            }

            // get the stencil value;
            img_cur.setPosition(loc_p);

            float L = -4*img_cur.get().getRealFloat();

            // Laplacian
            for (int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++)
            {
                img_cur.move(1, i);
                final float G_p = img_cur.get().getRealFloat();

                img_cur.move(-1,i);
                final float G_m = img_cur.get().getRealFloat();

                img_cur.move(-1, i);
                final float L_m = img_cur.get().getRealFloat();

                img_cur.setPosition(loc_p);

                L += G_p + L_m;

                // Calculate the gradient + convert into bin
                indexD[1-i] = (int) (Grad_Offset + G_p - G_m);
            }

            Lap_f.setPosition(loc_p);

            // Set the Laplacian field
            Lap_f.get().setReal(L);

            // Histogram bin conversion
            L += Lap_Offset;

            Lap_hist.setPosition((int)(L),0);
            Lap_hist.get().setReal(Lap_hist.get().getRealFloat() + f);

            Grad_dist.setPosition(indexD);
            Grad_dist.get().setReal(Grad_dist.get().getRealFloat() + f);
        }
    }

    private void convertGrad2dToCDF(Img<FloatType> GradD) {
        final RandomAccess<FloatType> Grad_dist = GradD.randomAccess();
        final int[] loc = new int[GradD.numDimensions()];

        // for each row
        for (int j = 0; j < GradD.dimension(1); ++j)
        {
            loc[1] = j;
            for (int i = 1; i < GradD.dimension(0) ; ++i)
            {

                loc[0] = i-1;
                Grad_dist.setPosition(loc);

                // Precedent float
                final float prec = Grad_dist.get().getRealFloat();

                // Move to the actual position
                Grad_dist.move(1, 0);

                // integration up to the current position
                Grad_dist.get().set(Grad_dist.get().getRealFloat() + prec);
            }
        }

        //col integration
        for (int j = 1; j < GradD.dimension(1); ++j)
        {
            // Move to the actual position
            loc[1] = j-1;

            for (int i = 0; i < GradD.dimension(0); ++i)
            {
                loc[0] = i;
                Grad_dist.setPosition(loc);

                // Precedent float
                final float prec = Grad_dist.get().getRealFloat();

                // Move to the actual position
                Grad_dist.move(1, 1);

                Grad_dist.get().set(Grad_dist.get().getRealFloat() + prec);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Show information about authors and paper.
     */
    private void showMessage()
     {
        // Create main window with panel to store gui components
       final JDialog win = new JDialog((JDialog)null, "Naturalization", true);
       final JPanel msg = new JPanel();
       msg.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

       // Create message not editable but still focusable for copying
        final JTextPane text = new JTextPane();
        text.setContentType("text/html");
        text.setText("<html>Y. Gong and I. F. Sbalzarini. Image enhancement by gradient distribution specification. In Proc. ACCV, <br>"
                + "12th Asian Conference on Computer Vision, Workshop on Emerging Topics in Image Enhancement and Restoration,<br>"
               + "pages w7–p3, Singapore, November 2014.<br><br>"
                + "Y. Gong and I. F. Sbalzarini, Gradient Distributions Priors for Biomedical Image Processing, 2014<br><a href=\"http://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3300\">http://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3300</a><br><br>"
                + "Y. Gong and I. F. Sbalzarini. A Natural-Scene Gradient Distribution Prior and its Application in Light-Microscopy Image Processing.<br>"
               + "IEEE Journal of Selected Topics in Signal Processing, Vol.10, No.1, February 2016, pages 99-114<br>"
               + "ISSN: 1932-4553, DOI: 10.1109/JSTSP.2015.2506122<br><br>"
               + "</html>");
       text.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 2));
        text.setEditable(false);
       msg.add(text);

       // Add button "Close" for closing window easily
       final JButton button = new JButton("Close");
       button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
           @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               win.dispose();

           }
       });
        msg.add(button);

        // Finally show window with message
        win.add(msg);
        win.pack();
        win.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        win.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean showDialog() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean setup(String aArgs) {
        setFilePrefix("naturalized_");
        return true;
    }
}
```

I want it to compile it again and get a .class file or a whole .jar file of this plugin.

Which sturcuture and datas I need for get a .class data?
What are with the import files, where i can get the ij, java, javax and net files? In which structure must it be.

I am a novice in Java and only know, that the compiled command is javac.

Comment: What a beautiful piece of code, thank God that's not CR section.

Comment: Sorry, but this is super basic stuff. There are **zillions** of good tutorials (or other questions here) explaining such things. You are expected to do some research yourself prior posting questions.

Comment: And honestly: unfortunately your question boils down to "somebody please please help me with this". But we do not regard such requests as *questions* in the scope of this site. Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) carefully to understand why that is. Then consider to either delete this question and putting up a new, more precise question within the scope of this community. Alternatively, you could [edit], rework and improve this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on linux there is a command to do it which is javac

just : javac HelloWorld.java

it might be the same thing on windows but i am not sure (install a virtual linux box if there is no other way)

If something goes wrong google the error

Comment: Note that you can add arguments if you want options

Comment: Can't you just build whole project? I see ```pom.xml```, you may use Maven here.

Comment: Thanks @Peteef for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compile a Java program from command line you should use the javac command and to invoke it just write java and then the name of your program. 
Compiling a file you will have the .class file that you are looking for.